# wpf datagrid combobox binding staticresource list of keyvalue pairs

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, staticresource

I hope someone can help me or post a link to related question, that would have the answer. I have read most of them and thats how I got this far...

So I have a datagrid with 3 columns, two of them are binded to one datatable and the third one that is a comboboxcolumn should be binded to the other one.

I binded the combobox column to a static resource.

What I don't uderstand how to transform a datatable to a list of keyvalue pairs that I want to use as a static resource for my comboboxcolumn.

```
public class MyClasificators:List<KeyValuePair<object, object>>
{

    public MyClasificators()
    {

        this.Add(new KeyValuePair<object, object>(1, "Test"));
        this.Add(new KeyValuePair<object,object>(2, "Test1"));
        this.Add(new KeyValuePair<object, object>(3, "Test2"));

    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<local:MyClasificators x:Key="clList"></local:MyClasificators>
```

Combobox column:

```
<dg:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="test">
    <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource clList}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" / >
         </DataTemplate>
      </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Now this works fine but how do I pass this table to the MyClassificators class and how do I convert it to list> :

```
DataTable country = new DataTable();
            country.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id_country", typeof(int)));
            country.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("name", typeof(string)));
            DS.Tables.Add(country);
```

Comment: So you want to put the content of MyClassificator in a DataTable ?

Comment: No the other way around. I want to put all of the entries of Datatable to MyClassificator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that "country" is your filled table, that column 0 is "id_country" and column 1 is "name" :

```
public MyClasificators()
{
    //Acquire "country" DataTable before this point

    foreach (DataRow row in country.Rows)
    {
        this.Add(new KeyValuePair<object, object>(row.ItemArray[0], row.ItemArray[1]));
    }
}
```

This will loop through all the rows in the DataTable and get the first two items of each row and add them respectively to the list ;)

Comment: Why thank you, kind sir! I must admit I never knew how friendy and helpfull are people around here.

Comment: I still do have a problem implementing this though. `code`  public class MyClasificators:List<KeyValuePair<object, object>>
    {
        
        public void _MyClasificators(DataTable country)
   {
                   foreach (DataRow row in country.Rows)
       {
           this.Add(new KeyValuePair<object, object>(row.ItemArray[0], row.ItemArray[1]));
       }
   }`code`  and in the main class I have `code` public void callMyClassificators()
        {
            MyClasificators clasif = new MyClasificators();
            clasif._MyClasificators(country);
        } `code`

Comment: What kind of problem do you have ?

Comment: It is telling me that The Object reference not set to an instance of an object, if I try to call the method "callMyClassificators"

Comment: Where are you pulling your country table from ?