# wpf binding to static resource

Tags: wpf, binding, staticresource

So I have  aproblem with binding in WPF. I am trying to bind a DataGrid ComboBoxColumn with a static resource but with no luck. I know where the problem is but I'm not sure how to fix it.

in XAML i have this:

```
<local:MyClasificators x:Key="clList"></local:MyClasificators>
```

and DataGridComboBoxColumn

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource clList}" DisplayMemberPath="Value"  ></ComboBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

code for the source I'm binding:

```
public class MyClasificators:List<KeyValuePair<object, object>>
{
    public void _MyClasificators(DataTable country)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in country.Rows)
        {
            this.Add(new KeyValuePair<object, object>(row.ItemArray[0], row.ItemArray[1]));
        }
    }
```

And the code for passing the DataTable:

```
public void callMyClassificators(DataTable country)
{
    MyClasificators clasif = new MyClasificators();
    clasif._MyClasificators(country);
}
```

I know that most probably I just have to edit the Resource part, but I'm not sure how should I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<local:MyClasificators x:Key="clList"></local:MyClasificators>
```

translates to something like:

```
Resources.Add("clList", new MyClasificators());
```

That's it, there's no data in your object.

You could create the resource `clList` from code, for example in app.xaml.cs:

```
var countryTable = ... // Get or create table here
var clList = new MyClasificators();
var clList.callMyClassificators(countryTable);
Resources.Add("clList", clList);
```

Comment: I know that there is no data in my object. The problem is I tried to modify an example I found here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622425/wpf-datagrid-combobox-binding-staticresource-list-of-keyvalue-pairs[link]

Comment: In this example the table is acquired in the constructor of the MyClassificator. That is why it works there...

Comment: Could you recommend me how I should go about this? I tried but I could not pass the DataTable differently.

Comment: @boo_boo_bear Where do you create or get the table? Before you instantiate MyClassificators?

Comment: I create the table in the main class before I call for the "callMyClassificators". In fact I am not even sure if this is the best way to go about binding to ComboBoxColumn in datagrid, but I failed to do it with ObservableCollection so I am trying to do it this way.

Comment: Are you familiar with the MVVM pattern? The best-practice way is to create a ViewModel, which holds the data that the view consumes. It's quite a complex topic, you will have to take some time to dig into it....

Answer (score 0):

From above code, it seems that an instance of MyClasificators is created in resource section. But MyClasificators (clList) does not have any items. It's an empty list. Place a break point in your code and check this.Resources["clList"] and check the count of items in it.

Comment: Well, yes that is exactly the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple problems.

1. in callMyClassificators, you create a new instance of MyClasificators. That instance is not the one you bind in Xaml. When you define a local resource, one instance is created there. That's the one your Combox is bound to, not the one you create in callMyClassificators. You should make sure xaml and code work on the same instance.
2. Let's say you fix No.1. When is "callMyClassificators" called? After the binding is done, there is no way for your MyClasificators to notify WPF that the list has changed. You could use a ObservableCollection> so that collection change will automatically be observed by WPF.

Comment: I already tried to do it with observable collection bu failed, that is why I was trying to make this solution work.